# ViewController won't reload properly on first Simulator launch

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a weird issue that I just found out when I re-installed and launched my project first time on Simulator

My main ViewController has a collection view that will show a list of recipes. After a recipe is added and navigated back to this screen, the list will reflect the update.
There is also a ScrollView that appears when `recipe.count > 0` with subview containing buttons (to filter list by category). The scrollview reflect the update on the recipes but it won't work on the very first launch in Simulator.

I've tried reloading collectionview, fetching recipe data on viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear but no luck with the first-time launch.

How can I make sure the first app launch experience is the same with the subsequent launches? Is there any known issue with first-time launch on Simulator that I should know about?

[image]

Here is the code that creates buttons and add to ScrollView.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    fetchRecipe()
    collection.reloadData()

    if recipes.count == 0 {
        categoryScrollView.hidden = true
        categoryScrollViewHeight.constant = 0
    } else {
        populateCategoryScrollView()
    }

}


func populateCategoryScrollView() {

    //Create category sort buttons based on fetched category.name and add to scrollview
    if recipes.count > 0 {

        var categories: [String] = []

        for recipe in recipes {
            if let value = recipe.category {
                let category = value as! RecipeCategory
                categories.append(category.name!)
            }
        }

        var distinctCategories = Array(Set(categories))
        var widthStack = 0

        if distinctCategories.count != 0 {

            for subView in categoryScrollView.subviews {
                subView.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            for i in 0..<distinctCategories.count {
                //Pilot button creation to get width
                let frame1 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: 80, height: 40 )
                let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
                button.setTitle("\(distinctCategories[i])", forState: .Normal)
                button.sizeToFit()

                let buttonWidth = Int(button.frame.size.width)
                var frame2: CGRect

                if i == 0 {
                    frame2 = CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: buttonWidth+20, height: 30 )
                } else {
                    frame2 = CGRect(x: 10 + widthStack, y: 6, width: buttonWidth+20, height: 30 )
                }

                widthStack += buttonWidth+32

                let button1 = UIButton(frame: frame2)
                let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "\(distinctCategories[i])".uppercaseString, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: 1.0, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()])
                button1.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, forState: .Normal)
                button1.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13.0)
                button1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
                button1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
                button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                button1.addTarget(self, action: "filterByCategory:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                self.categoryScrollView.addSubview(button1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show some code - How do you add/configure the scroll view?

Comment: I've updated the question with code.

Comment: Does self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 have any effect in viewDidAppear?

Comment: Just tried `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` but no effect.

Comment: is `fetchRecipe` asynchronous?  You should move the `if recipes.count == 0 ...` code into a function and then call this function whenever `recipes` changes since recipes will initially be empty and you need to make sure it is shown as soon as a recipe is added

Comment: `fetchRecipe` is not asynchronous. When I print `recipes.count` right after `fetchRecipe()` it has effect.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint?  What is the count of recipes when you see the problem?

Comment: I've added `print` in various places and on the first launch after I added one recipe and navigated back to main viewcontroller, it show on the console `ViewDidAppear with recipe count 1`
`populateCategoryScrollview() called`
`button added to scrollview` So it runs all the codes but just not reflecting it on the UI.

Comment: @SeongLee you can do a view debugging in Xcode to see what is wrong with the view hierarchy.

Comment: `populateCategoryScrollview` doesn't change the constraints & hidden property.  I would suggest that you move the `if` statement into that function and make sure that the constraint constant and hidden property are set correctly in an `else` clause. That way if the number of recipes > 0 then the scrollview will be unhidden/shown

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, too. I moved if statement to the function and made viewDidAppear to call the function unconditionally.

`func populateCategoryScrollView() {
        if recipes.count > 0 {     
            ..
        } else {
            categoryScrollView.hidden = true
            categoryScrollViewHeight.constant = 0
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you enter the application, the `recipes.count` is 0, so you are hiding the scroll view by the constraint `categoryScrollViewHeight.constant = 0`. So next time you create a new recipe, the scroll view is still with a zero height. That's why you didn't see the scroll on first time launch.

Comment: That was it... I always have some recipes in the subsequent launches so I didn't see this problem. Activating ScrollView by 
adding `categoryScrollView.hidden = false
            categoryScrollViewHeight.constant = 48` to `if recipes.count > 0 {` solved this problem.

Comment: The sample code you provide is very limited, but I guess all recipes are saved somewhere. So the first time you launch the application, the recipes are empty, the height constraint will be set to 0. But is the following launches, the recipes fetched will not be empty, right? I assume you have added some recipes in the first launch, then the if clause wont even be executed.